# measure theory-find a function

Tags: measure-theory

Find a function $f:\Bbb R$ $\to$ $\Bbb R$ which is continuous, non bounded, and $f \in L^2$.

This is a problem from my exams today on measure theory. Unfortunately i couldn't solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My approach would be to make the graph a union of triangles starting at $x=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ with increasing heights (with 0 in between), but whose widths decrease rapidly enough that the total square integral is finite.

Comment: what about $x=-1,-2,-3,.. $ ? i thought of the triangles too. But not only the positive $x$.

Comment: There's no need to make a doubly infinite set of triangles, so it's sufficient to keep $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: ok i get that but what is the $f(x)$ ? i can't find a formula that meets the requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following function satisfies your requirements:
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
n^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^3}- \lvert{x-n\rvert}} & \text{ if } \lvert{x-n\rvert} < \frac{1}{n^3} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N} \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{matrix} \right.
$$
Note that $f(n) = \sqrt{n}$ so the function is definitely not bounded. But the width of each triangle is $\frac{2}{n^3}$ and the height is $n$. So the area of each triangle is $\frac{1}{n^2}$, which can be summed.

**Addition:**

Alternatively consider the following function as described by  Daniel Schepler:
$$ 
f(x) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} 
2^n n \left( \frac{1}{2^n} - \lvert x- n \rvert \right) & \text{ if } \lvert x -n \rvert < \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N} \\ 
0 & \text{ else }
\end{matrix} \right.
$$
We have then for any $1 \leq p < + \infty$ that 
$$
\lVert f \rVert_p^p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\frac{1}{2^n} 2(2^n n)^p 
x^p dx = \frac{2}{p+1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty  (2^n n)^p 
\left( \frac{1}{2^n} \right)^{p+1} = \frac{2}{p+1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{n^p}{2^n} $$
which converges due to the ratio test.
So this function is in $L^p$ for every $1 \leq p < +\infty$, is unbounded and continuous.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you. I edited it and simply took the square root of my solution which should make it $L^2$ if I'm correct.

Comment: Actually, if you make a series of triangles of height $n$ and width $1/2^n$, you get an example where $f \in L^p$ whenever $1 \le p < \infty$ but $f \not\in L^\infty$, and $f$ is still continuous.

Comment: Is this function not continuous then? I agree it might not be the prettiest solution, but should still be continuous.

Comment: You're right, it is continuous.  I was just suggesting a slight modification which gives an example with a significantly stronger and interesting property, without destroying the continuity.

Comment: You're right, that is indeed pretty neat. I added it to the solution.

Comment: I think the sum should be $\frac{2}{p+1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^p}{2^n}$.  (As an aside, my thinking was a crude approximation, that the $p$-power integral over the $n$th interval is bounded by $n^p$ times the width of the interval.)

Comment: Of course, thank you for another correction. :D